# Algorithm that takes 2 'similar' matrices and 'aligns' one to another

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, linear-algebra

First of all, the title is very bad, due to my lack of a concise vocabulary. I'll try to describe what I'm doing and then ask my question again.

**Background Info**

Let's say I have 2 matrices of size `n` x `m`, where `n` is the number of experimental observation vectors, each of length `m` (the time series over which the observations were collected). One of these matrices is the original matrix, called `S`, the other which is a reconstructed version of `S`, called `Y`.

---

*Let's assume that `Y` properly reconstructs `S`. However due to the limitations of the reconstruction algorithm, `Y` can't determine the true amplitude of the vectors in `S`, nor is it guaranteed to provide the proper sign for those vectors (the vectors might be flipped). Also, the order of the observation vectors in `Y` might not match the original ordering of the corresponding vectors in `S`.*

**My Question**

Is there an algorithm or technique to generate a new matrix which is a 'realignment' of `Y` to `S`, so that when `Y` and `S` are normalized, the algorithm can (1) find the vectors in `Y` that match the vectors in `S` and restore the original ordering of the vectors and (2) likewise match the signs of the vectors?

---

As always, I really appreciate all help given. Thanks!

Comment: is this a homework? cuz I can't imagine somebody would need this in real life and DONT know how to solve it already...

Comment: zvolkov: no it's not homework... and I already thought of the method given by Yuval A, but it's possible that I might have a very very large data set, and so I want to avoid quadratic time methods if possible- I was wondering whether there was something faster. As for me not knowing how to do this... well, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: There isn't any information about, or constraints on how the vectors might be deranged, so I believe you're stuck with Yuval's process. If you provided the reconstruction algorithm, there might be some property of it that could be exploited to speed things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply calculating the normalized form for each vector in both matrices and comparing? That should give you an exacty one-to-one match for each vector in each matrix.

The normal form of a vector is one that conforms to:

```
v_norm = v / ||v||
```

where `||v||` is the euclidean norm for the vector. For `v=(v1, v2, ..., vn)` we have `||v|| = sqrt(v1^2 + ... + vn^2)`.

From there you can reconstruct their order, and return each vector its original length and direction (the vector or its opposite).

The algorithm should be fairly simple from here on, just decide on your implementation. <strike>This method should be of quadratic complexity</strike>. Per the comment, you can indeed achieve `O(nlogn)` complexity on this algorithm. If you need something better than that, linear complexity - specifically, you're going to need a much more complicated algorithm which I can't think of right now.

Comment: Why is it quadratic? Sort each vector of Y and S (along with pre-sort row numbers) and then they're easy to match up row by row. You also have to normalize the sign by, say, forcing the first non-zero element of each vector to be positive. Then it's all n log n.